TicTacToe Minimax function, and bestMove Function don't call tTinker button commands
I've been trying to create a tictactoe game that has a GUI using tKinter and utilizes a minimax function to simulate a computer playing against the player. The player should be X and the computer should be O. I've implemented a minimax function and a best move function to use the score from the minimax function to call the button where the highest score lies click command, but it doesn't work for several reasons.
I've tried changing where certain variables are created to not have to run into the issue of variables not being accessible, and I've looked at various other implementations and tried to mimic their approaches, but I've had no success.
The base game however still works as intended, when a player wins, the buttons turn red and a messagebox appears exclaiming their victory.
import numpy as np 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import *




root = Tk()
root.title("ARISE TIC-TAC-TOE")


#Building buttons

b1 = Button(root, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 3, width = 6, bg ="SystemButtonFace", command = lambda: b_click(b1) )
b2 = Button(root, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 3, width = 6, bg ="SystemButtonFace", command = lambda: b_click(b2) )
b3 = Button(root, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 3, width = 6, bg ="SystemButtonFace", command = lambda: b_click(b3) )

b4 = Button(root, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 3, width = 6, bg ="SystemButtonFace", command = lambda: b_click(b4) )
b5 = Button(root, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 3, width = 6, bg ="SystemButtonFace", command = lambda: b_click(b5) )
b6 = Button(root, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 3, width = 6, bg ="SystemButtonFace", command = lambda: b_click(b6) )

b7 = Button(root, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 3, width = 6, bg ="SystemButtonFace", command = lambda: b_click(b7) )
b8 = Button(root, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 3, width = 6, bg ="SystemButtonFace", command = lambda: b_click(b8) )
b9 = Button(root, text = " ", font = ("Helvetica", 20), height = 3, width = 6, bg ="SystemButtonFace", command = lambda: b_click(b9) )


gameboard = np.array([[b1, b2, b3],
                    [b4, b5, b6],
                    [b7, b8, b9]])
temp_gameboard = np.array([[b1["text"], b2["text"], b3["text"]],
                    [b4["text"], b5["text"], b6["text"]],
                    [b7["text"], b8["text"], b9["text"]]])






clicked = True
global depth 
b_move = (-1, -1) 
depth = 0
count = 0
score = 0

#Disable all buttons

def disable_all():
    b1.config(state= DISABLED)
    b2.config(state= DISABLED)
    b3.config(state= DISABLED)
    b4.config(state= DISABLED)
    b5.config(state= DISABLED)
    b6.config(state= DISABLED)
    b7.config(state= DISABLED)
    b8.config(state= DISABLED)
    b9.config(state= DISABLED)


#Win Checker

def checkifwon():
    global winner
    winner = False

    if b1["text"] == "X" and b2["text"] == "X" and b3["text"] == "X":
        b1.config(bg = "red")
        b2.config(bg = "red")
        b3.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = 1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("PLAYER WINS!")
        disable_all()
        return True
    elif b4["text"] == "X" and b5["text"] == "X" and b6["text"] == "X":
        b4.config(bg = "red")
        b5.config(bg = "red")
        b6.config(bg = "red")  
        winner = True
        score = 1
        messagebox.showinfo("PLAYER WINS!")
        disable_all()
        return True

    elif b7["text"] == "X" and b8["text"] == "X" and b9["text"] == "X":
        b7.config(bg = "red")
        b8.config(bg = "red")
        b9.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = 1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("PLAYER WINS!")
        disable_all()
        return True

    elif b1["text"] == "X" and b4["text"] == "X" and b7["text"] == "X":
        b1.config(bg = "red")
        b4.config(bg = "red")
        b7.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = 1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("PLAYER WINS!")
        disable_all()
        return True
    elif b2["text"] == "X" and b5["text"] == "X" and b8["text"] == "X":
        b2.config(bg = "red")
        b5.config(bg = "red")
        b8.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = 1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("PLAYER WINS!")
        disable_all()
        return True
    elif b3["text"] == "X" and b6["text"] == "X" and b9["text"] == "X":
        b3.config(bg = "red")
        b6.config(bg = "red")
        b9.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = 1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("PLAYER WINS!")
        disable_all()
        return True
    elif b1["text"] == "X" and b5["text"] == "X" and b9["text"] == "X":
        b1.config(bg = "red")
        b5.config(bg = "red")
        b9.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = 1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("PLAYER WINS!")
        disable_all()
        return True
    elif b3["text"] == "X" and b5["text"] == "X" and b7["text"] == "X":
        b3.config(bg = "red")
        b5.config(bg = "red")
        b7.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = 1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("PLAYER WINS!")
        disable_all()
        return True

## Check if O has won

    if b1["text"] == "O" and b2["text"] == "O" and b3["text"] == "O":
        b1.config(bg = "red")
        b2.config(bg = "red")
        b3.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = -1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("O WINS", "CONGRATULATIONS")
        disable_all()
        return False

    elif b4["text"] == "O" and b5["text"] == "O" and b6["text"] == "O":
        b4.config(bg = "red")
        b5.config(bg = "red")
        b6.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = -1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("O WINS", "CONGRATULATIONS")
        disable_all()
        return False

    elif b7["text"] == "O" and b8["text"] == "O" and b9["text"] == "O":
        b7.config(bg = "red")
        b8.config(bg = "red")
        b9.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = -1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("O WINS", "CONGRATULATIONS")
        disable_all()
        return False

    elif b1["text"] == "O" and b4["text"] == "O" and b7["text"] == "O":
        b1.config(bg = "red")
        b4.config(bg = "red")
        b7.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = -1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("O WINS", "CONGRATULATIONS")
        disable_all()
        return False
    elif b2["text"] == "O" and b5["text"] == "O" and b8["text"] == "O":
        b2.config(bg = "red")
        b5.config(bg = "red")
        b8.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = -1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("O WINS", "CONGRATULATIONS")
        disable_all()
        return False
    elif b3["text"] == "O" and b6["text"] == "O" and b9["text"] == "O":
        b3.config(bg = "red")
        b6.config(bg = "red")
        b9.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = -1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("O WINS", "CONGRATULATIONS")
        disable_all()
        return False
    elif b1["text"] == "O" and b5["text"] == "O" and b9["text"] == "O":
        b1.config(bg = "red")
        b5.config(bg = "red")
        b9.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = -1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("O WINS", "CONGRATULATIONS")
        disable_all()
        return False
    elif b3["text"] == "O" and b5["text"] == "O" and b7["text"] == "O":
        b3.config(bg = "red")
        b5.config(bg = "red")
        b7.config(bg = "red")
        winner = True
        score = -1
        

        messagebox.showinfo("O WINS", "CONGRATULATIONS")
        disable_all()
        return False
    score = 0

#Saving all 8 combinations for winning a game



# Computer logic 
# 1. Simulate a b click
# 2. It has to store it's last move
# 3. It has to know to only go once
# 4. It has to use minimax for the logic behind it's move

def b_click(b):

    global clicked, count

    if b["text"] == " " and clicked == True :
        b["text"] = "X"
        clicked = False
        count+= 1
        checkifwon()
        bestMove()
        #minimax(temp_gameboard, 0, True)
    elif b["text"] == " " and clicked == False :
        b["text"] = "O"
        clicked = True
        count+=1
        checkifwon()
        #minimax(temp_gameboard, 0, True)
    else :
       raise  messagebox.showerror("That square has already been selected!")
    return 0


# Computer defines depth, the amount of turns left in a game

def score():
    if checkifwon() == True:
       output = 10 - depth
       return output
       
    elif checkifwon() == False:
        output = depth - 10
        return output
    else:
        return 0
    
def minimax(t_gameboard, depth, is_max):
    if (checkifwon() == True or checkifwon() == False):
        return score()
   
    possible_gameboard = gameboard

    if is_max:
        best_score = -float('inf')
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if possible_gameboard[i][j] == '':
                    possible_gameboard[i][j] = 'O'
                    score = minimax(possible_gameboard, depth + 1, False)

                    possible_gameboard[i][j] = ''
                    best_score = max(score, best_score)
        return best_score

    else:
        best_score = float('inf')
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                if possible_gameboard[i][j] == '':
                    possible_gameboard[i][j] = 'X'
                    score = minimax(possible_gameboard, depth + 1, True)
                    possible_gameboard[i][j] = ''
                    best_score = min(score, best_score)
        return best_score

def bestMove(temp_gameboard):
    b_move = (-1, -1)    
    
    best_Val = float('inf')

    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):

            if(temp_gameboard[i][j] == " "):
                temp_gameboard[i][j] = "O"

                if(moveVal > best_Val):
                    b_move = (i, j)
                    best_Val = moveVal
                moveVal = minimax(temp_gameboard, 0, False)
                temp_gameboard[i][j] = " "


varX = b_move[0]
varY = b_move[1]
print(gameboard[varX][varY])

 










    

# Recursive Minimax function



b1.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
b2.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
b3.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

b4.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
b5.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
b6.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

b7.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
b8.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
b9.grid(row = 2, column = 2)


 
root.mainloop()

Sorry if some of my documentation is a bit over the place, I've been playing around with this project for around 48 hours total and I still can't wrap my head around it. I'm a beginner so any help is highly appreciated.
Here's more information, I didn't realize that I hadn't given enough.
The minimax function doesn't work as intended. It's supposed to be a recursive function that should eventually outputs a best score for the maximizer or the minimizer. The minimax function is called by the bestMove function. The bestMove function should use the output of the minimax function to simulate a button click from the b_click function above the "computer logic" section of the game. However this call doesn't work because the variable b_move isn't being detected (at least that's what vscode has said). Also, I'm unsure if the way I've tried to call the b_click function near the end of the bestMove function is correct in Python.
Here's what I've tried.
I've tried making b_move a global variable, but to no avail so I believe it may be a scope issue.
I also tried initializing b_move outside of the function but it also doesn't work as intended either.
For the minimax, I've tried several implementations, some that create scores for certain scenarios within the function, but I chose the implementation where the score for a game, the one that the minimax function would use, is incremented with the pre-existing winning conditions.
Currently I have the function printing the gameboard of varX and varY. Ideally it should be giving me the button of which those variables point to where 0,0 is the first square/button on the tKinter grid.
Hope this helps with understanding this problem. Once again I'm very green when it comes to code, and even greener with Python. Please be patient as I'm still learning.

Please provide more information on what does not work and add a few lines on what you have tried.

I added much more information to the problem. Please tell me if any more is needed and I'll be more than ready to respond within reasonable time. Thank you

line 270, in b_click
bestMove()
TypeError: bestMove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'temp_gameboard'

On line 270, comment  out this: #bestMove(). Your code should be working.

Still, my program should be able to utilize minimax and bestmove to simulate a button click exactly where the minimax function says it should be.

Your code has issues: call bestMove() without passing required argument; moveVal is undefined inside bestMove(), etc.

This approach of defining your board and game state with tight links to tkinter is bad practice. Best practice is to separate game logic from UI concerns. See separation of concerns.
